# How to anchor visual element in xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, mobile, resolution

I am making a landing page for this application I am developing. I have done a pre-render for the background and am currently working out how to place elements above it so that it appears seamless. Currently, I have placed the first element, an entry box, approximately where I want it to be. My issue now is that I need It to remain there regardless of the screen size it may be displayed on. My intuition tells me this can be done with AnchorX and AnchorY.

Here is my code:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" Source="{local:ImageResource Untitled.Images.predrawVers2.png}" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image >
            <Grid AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="24" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="317" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="420" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                <Entry Placeholder="System name" PlaceholderColor="Aqua" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"></Entry>
            </Grid>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m sure you’re following the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout but it seems like you’re going to use a lot of layout bounds and flags. i would recommend not using that pre rendered background for the form at least, it’s going to take a lot of time to be reliable, and you might as well build that background in Xamarin at that point

Comment: Hmm okay, thank you for your feedback. Im gonna try experimenting a little longer to see if I can do what I want reliably but if not I might as well go that route.

Comment: You should know position of UI in the picture first. And the set the same position to the UI in your proeject. I think it's hard to achieve . You can have a try with [relative-layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout).